# JQuery: limit appendChild

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to limit appendChild when calling a certain image, here's how the flow goes

**USER's INPUT(label):** Albania

**Display(buttton):** click

**OUTPUT:** Image that is limited to one

In my Javascript code its working without any problems the image is output and it is only limited to one: http://jsfiddle.net/Bh9h7/

**JAVASCRIPT CODE:**

```
var display = false;

function addimage() {
    selected = document.getElementById("country").value;

    if (selected === "") {
        return false;;
    } else {
        var src = "img2/" + selected + ".jpg";
        var img = document.createElement("img");

        img.src = src;
        if (!display) {
            container.appendChild(img);
            img.style.display = "inline";
            display = true;
            console.log(display);
            console.log(country);
            console.log(selected);
        }
    }
}
```

But when I put it on my Jquery, it stills output the image but it has no limit meaning everytime the user clicks the display button a new image is output.

**JQUERY CODE:**

```
function mapAddress(result) {
    marker.setPosition(result.geometry.location);
    marker.setMap(map);
    map.fitBounds(result.geometry.viewport);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Validate').click(function () {
        $('#address').val($('#address').val().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim());

        var address = encodeURI($('#address').val());
        var url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + address + '&sensor=true';

        $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
            function getCountry(addrComponents) {
                for (var i = 0; i < addrComponents.length; i++) {
                    if (addrComponents[i].types[0] === "street_number") {
                        document.getElementById('street_number').value = addrComponents[i].long_name;
                    }

                    if (addrComponents[i].types[0] === "country") {
                        document.getElementById('country').value = addrComponents[i].long_name;
                    }
                }
                //return false;
            }
            console.log(getCountry(data.results[0].address_components));
        });

        var x = document.getElementById("address").value;
        if (x === "" || x === "Input Address Here") {
            alert("No Input");
        }

        var res = '';
        var address = document.getElementById('address').value;

        geocoder.geocode({
            'address': address
        }, function (results, process) {
            switch (process) {
                case google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK:
                    $('#valid').val('Address is Valid');
                    $('#res').val(results[0].formatted_address);
                    res = results[0].formatted_address;
                    mapAddress(results[0]);

                    var display = false;
                    selected = document.getElementById("country").value;

                    if (selected === "") {
                        return false;;
                    } else {
                        var src = "img2/" + selected + ".jpg";
                        var img = document.createElement("img");
                        img.src = src;

                        if (!display) {
                            container.appendChild(img);
                            img.style.display = "inline";
                            display = true;
                            console.log(display);
                            console.log(country);
                            console.log(selected);
                        }
                    }

                    var y = document.getElementById("street_number").value;
                    if (y === "") {
                        document.getElementById("valid2").value = "Could not find street number";
                    }

                    var address = $('#address').val();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'Corrections.php',
                        data: {
                            var1: address,
                            var2: res
                        },

                        success: function (data) {
                            console.log('success final');
                            document.getElementById('cor').value = data;
                        }
                    });
                    break;
                case google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS:
                    var x = document.getElementById("address").value;
                    if (x === "" || x === "Input Address Here") {
                        return false;
                    }
                    document.getElementById('valid').value = 'Invalid Address';
                    break;
                default:
                    alert("Error");
            }
        });
    });
});

function clear() {
    document.getElementById('valid').value = '';
    map.setCenter(defaultLatLng);
    map.setZoom(0);
    marker.setMap(null);
}

function clearbtn() {
    document.getElementById("address").value = "Input Address Here";
    document.getElementById("res").value = "Results will be displayed here";
    document.getElementById("valid").value = "";
    document.getElementById("valid2").value = "";
    document.getElementById("cor").value = "Changes will be displayed here";
    document.getElementById("street_number").value = "";
    document.getElementById("route").value = "";
    document.getElementById("locality").value = "";
    document.getElementById("administrative_area_level_1").value = "";
    document.getElementById("country").value = "";
    document.getElementById("postal_code").value = "";

    selected = document.getElementById("country").value;
    display = false;
    document.getElementById("country").value = "";
    selected = null;
    var MyContainer = document.getElementById("container");
    MyContainer.removeChild(MyContainer.childNodes[0]);

    map.setCenter(defaultLatLng);
    map.setZoom(0);
    marker.setMap(null);
}
```

can't seem to find the problem, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a jsFiddle of your jQuery code (like the pure JS one)?

Comment: @Xotic750 w8 sir I'll make one

Comment: It's hard to figure out what is your mistake with all this code mixed up. As i see it, `display` will always be equal to false

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/29pXj/ @Xotic750

Comment: Doesn't seem to have any HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, it looks as though display will always be false so an image will always be appended to container.

My suggestion would be to give the img an id.  Under `img.src = src;`, add another line `img.id = 'someImage'`.

Now you have something to look for when attempting to output the image.  So instead of using `if(!display)` to figure out if you need to still append the image, you can use `if ($('#someImage').length == 0)`

Answer (score 1):

That's because everytime the user clicks the button, you call you click event handler.
In your event handler you declare a new variable `display = false`. This variable is checked and than set to true. But every new click, 'resests' the variable to `false` again *(in fact it generates a complete new one, because the old one is out of scope)*, checks it again and adds a new picture.

So you have to either place the variable outside of the click event handler, or you get rid of it and better check if the image you want to append is already existing.

```
var src = "img2/" + selected + ".jpg";
if($('img#yourId').length == 0) {
  $('<img/>', {
    id: "yourId",
    src: src })
    .css('display', 'inline')
    .appendTo(container);
}
```

For yourId you either declare one like you probably do for each button or e.g. just read other attributes. I would have made an example for that too, but you did not provide us with any HTML.